# QQmlPropertyMap Insert; Mysteriously Inserting None, or Removing Other Values

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I'm working in PySide2 and QML, and QQmlPropertyList is doing two things I find very odd.

The first is that assigning a QObject as a value doesn't work if it's created in the same statement:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlPropertyMap

qmap = QQmlPropertyMap()
qmap.insert('test_key', QObject())
print(qmap.value('test_key'))
```

Output:

```
None
```

Maybe this has something to do with the timing with which a QObject is initialized? It can be fixed by assigning it to a variable first:

```py
qmap = QQmlPropertyMap()

obj = QObject()
qmap.insert('test_key', obj)

print(qmap.value('test_key'))
```

```
<PySide2.QtCore.QObject(0x7fe8f26b5eb0) at 0x107075ec0>
```

But it gets stranger. Bear with me. Assigning two QObjects works:

```py
qmap = QQmlPropertyMap()

obj = QObject()
qmap.insert('test_key', obj)

obj2 = QObject()
qmap.insert('test_key2', obj2)

print(qmap.value('test_key'))
print(qmap.value('test_key2'))
```

```
<PySide2.QtCore.QObject(0x7f85f7f269e0) at 0x10d32b080>
<PySide2.QtCore.QObject(0x7f85f7f26b70) at 0x10d32b100>
```

I can even assign the same object to multiple keys:

```py
qmap = QQmlPropertyMap()

obj = QObject()
qmap.insert('test_key', obj)
qmap.insert('test_key2', obj)

print(qmap.value('test_key'))
print(qmap.value('test_key2'))
```

```
<PySide2.QtCore.QObject(0x7fde37d7d9d0) at 0x105cdc140>
<PySide2.QtCore.QObject(0x7fde37d7d9d0) at 0x105cdc140>
```

But if I reuse the same variable name for two different objects, the first key's value somehow gets erased:

```py
qmap = QQmlPropertyMap()

obj = QObject()
qmap.insert('test_key', obj)

obj = QObject()
qmap.insert('test_key2', obj)

print(qmap.value('test_key'))
print(qmap.value('test_key2'))
```

```
None
<PySide2.QtCore.QObject(0x7fcecaf072f0) at 0x111ba60c0>
```

How can this be? Is PySide doing some sort of hidden magic with runtime variable names? In this example it's trivial, but it caused a bug in my code that was hard to isolate, and I'd like to understand this better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an object and assign it the same variable the previous object is destroyed, that can be observed with the following test:

```
class Foo:
    def __del__(self):
        print("destroyed")

print("before creating Foo object: 1")
foo = Foo()
print("after creating Foo object: 1")
print("before creating Foo object: 2")
foo = Foo()
print("after creating Foo object: 2")
```

Output

```
before creating Foo object: 1
after creating Foo object: 1
before creating Foo object: 2
destroyed
after creating Foo object: 2
destroyed
```

As you can see the first destroyed is called when the second object is assigned to the same variable. So that is not the magic of PySide2 but of python, that the same can be verified with the destroyed signal.

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject


print("before creating QObject object: 1")
qobject = QObject()
qobject.destroyed.connect(lambda _id=id(qobject): print("destroyed1: ", _id))
print("after creating QObject object: 1")
print("before creating QObject object: 2")
qobject = QObject()
qobject.destroyed.connect(lambda _id=id(qobject): print("destroyed2: ", _id))
print("after creating QObject object: 2")
```

Output:

```
before creating QObject object: 1
after creating QObject object: 1
before creating QObject object: 2
destroyed1:  <PySide2.QtCore.QObject(0x562c1b6ee2f0) at 0x7f4a1faece40>
after creating QObject object: 2
```

If you want that problem not to happen then using the *super powers* of Qt you can pass the objects as parent of the "qmap", so the ownership will be held by the QObject and it will no longer be handled by python:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlPropertyMap


qmap = QQmlPropertyMap()

obj = QObject(qmap)
qmap.insert("test_key", obj)

obj = QObject(qmap)
qmap.insert("test_key2", obj)

print(qmap.value("test_key"))
print(qmap.value("test_key2"))
```

Output:

```
<PySide2.QtCore.QObject(0x559629d1e230) at 0x7fef951f01c0>
<PySide2.QtCore.QObject(0x559629d1eae0) at 0x7fef951f0240>
```

**Update:**

To understand better, we must know that the QObject of PySide2 (also applies to PyQt5) is a wrapper of the QObject of Qt, that is, it is something like:

```
class PyQObject:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._qobject_cpp = CPPQObject(*args)
        # ...
    def __del__(self):
        delete self._qobject_cpp
```

Comment: I would have expected the property map object to naturally keep references to its values, but that last bit does the trick—I guess unintuitive stuff like this just happens when a Python framework is a wrapper on a C++ framework.